# AngularJS keep template data when switching route?

Tags: angularjs

In state llantas.ordenes I have a jqGrid and other controls as well as in llantas.inventarios
so whenever I switch from #/llantas/ordenes to #/llantas/inventarios I loose the controls data and the jqGrid table is being redraw, so the question is if its possible to keep view data when switching from route to route?

This is my router.js:

```
    ng.route(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        // Now set up the states
        $stateProvider
            .state('llantas', {
                url: "/Llantas",
                templateUrl: "templates/llantas/index.html"
            })  

                // Ordenes
                .state('llantas.ordenes', {
                    url: "/ordenes",
                    templateUrl: "templates/llantas/ordenes/index.html",
                    controller: function($scope, $injector) {
                        require(['js/controllers/llantas/ordenes/index'], function(llantasOrdenesIndexCtrl) {
                            $injector.invoke(llantasOrdenesIndexCtrl, this, {'$scope': $scope});
                        });
                    }
                })




                // Inventarios
                .state('llantas.inventarios', {
                    url: "/inventarios",
                    templateUrl: "templates/llantas/inventarios/index.html",
                    controller: function($scope, $injector) {
                        require(['js/controllers/llantas/inventarios/index'], function(llantasInventariosIndexCtrl) {
                            $injector.invoke(llantasInventariosIndexCtrl, this, {'$scope': $scope});
                        });
                    }
                })
    });
```

Comment: set reloadOnSearch = false, that way the controller will not be reloaded when the search query changes

Comment: id does'nt work, I have set it along with each route view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the UI Router and set reloadOnSearch = false on every route.